# why is my previous result not clearing when i submit a new search?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios, addeventlistener, omdbapi

I am trying to print new result every time I search but the output keeps adding after the previous one, what I want is to clear previous result and display new results on `eventListener` submit. Here is my javascript code:

```
const form = document.querySelector("#searchForm")
const icon = document.querySelector("#tvIcon")
form.addEventListener("submit", async(event)=>{
event.preventDefault();
    const search = form.elements.query.value;
    const config = {params: {q: search}}
    const res = await axios.get("http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows", config)
    // console.log(res.data)
    makeImages(res.data);
    form.elements.query.value = "";
});

const makeImages = (show)=>{
    let tvPics = document.querySelector("#tvImages")
    for(let result of show){
    if(result.show.image){
    let img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = result.show.image.medium;
    tvPics.append(img)
    } 
    }
};
```

Comment: Because you're appending and not removing or replacing... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Comment: @Michael Can you provide with more clear context to this?

Comment: Try calling `tvPics.innerHTML = ''` before your for loop inside `makeImages` via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: @Dominik thank you soo much ive just added it and it worked, i appreciate it man